# Fix multiple console logs useEffect?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have this problem where my code console logs 3 times at page load and also increments it's index. I have no clue as to why this is happening. I've tried moving some stuff in and out of a `useEffect` but this didn't help. I am using the `typewriter-effect` module together with `NextJS`. I've setup a minimal reproduce example here: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/sleepy-shadow-ccvg97

When viewing the console log throughout the app you will notice that the index will be one too high. I know I could probably just set the index -1 after the page is done loading or something like that but I don't think that that would be a 'clean' way of solving this issue.

In case you'd like to look at the code through Stack Overflow:

```js
const words = ['innovative<br/>thinker', 'creative<br/>mind', 'web<br/>designer'];

const determineArticle = () => {
        const word = words[currentWordIndex];
        console.log(word);
        const vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'];
        const firstLetter = word.toLowerCase()[0];
        console.log(vowels.includes(firstLetter) ? 'an' : 'a');
    }

    const [currentWordIndex, setCurrentWordIndex] = useState(0);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (Number.isInteger(currentWordIndex)) determineArticle();
    }, [currentWordIndex]);

    const typeWord = async (typewriter) => {
        for (let i = 0, len = words.length; i < len; i++) {
            await new Promise((resolve) => {
                typewriter
                    .callFunction(() => {
                        if (currentWordIndex == 15) setCurrentWordIndex(0);
                        setCurrentWordIndex((prevIndex) => prevIndex + 0.5);
                        resolve();
                    })
                    .typeString(words[i])
                    .pauseFor(2500)
                    .deleteAll()
                    .start();
            });
        }
    };
```

And here is the html:

```html
<TypeWriter
    options={{
    autoStart: true,
    loop: true,
}}
    onInit={(typewriter) => {
          typeWord(typewriter);
    }}
/>
```

Also a screenshot for a visual example:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi the probleme is strictmode, in next is in :

```json
//next.config.js

module.exports = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
}
```

You can control it with simple variable:

```
let ignore;
 useEffect(() => {
      if(ignore){return;};
        if (Number.isInteger(currentWordIndex)) determineArticle();


    return () => {
         ignore = true;
       }
    }, [currentWordIndex]);
```

Let me know if it works.

Comment: StrictMode is her for help you is prevent involuntary side effect.

Answer (score 0):

In your shared example of CodeSandbox, removing the **StrictMode** from index file stopped console logs from happening twice. Please check this once.

[image]

Comment: This doesn't work. Like mentioned in my question I am using NextJS. My real example does the same as the codesandbox but it not using StrictMode.

Comment: @MarkdG Did you try explicitly turning it off in your [config](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/next-config-js/reactStrictMode)? (Not that I'd suggest turning it off, but this will allow you to see if its what's causing the issue)